# Flume Sink to Spark using Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, flume

**My Flume configuration**

```
source_agent.sources = tail
source_agent.sources.tail.type = exec
source_agent.sources.tail.command = python loggen.py
source_agent.sources.tail.batchSize = 1
source_agent.sources.tail.channels = memoryChannel
#memory-channel
source_agent.channels = memoryChannel
source_agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
source_agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
source_agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity=10000
source_agent.channels.memoryChannel.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
source_agent.channels.memoryChannel.byteCapacity = 800000
# Send to Flume Collector on saprk sink
source_agent.sinks = spark
source_agent.sinks.spark.type=org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.sink.SparkSink
source_agent.sinks.spark.batchSize=100
source_agent.sinks.spark.channel = memoryChannel
source_agent.sinks.spark.hostname=localhost
source_agent.sinks.spark.port=1234
```

**My Spark-Scala Code**

```
    package com.thanga.twtsteam
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._
 import org.apache.spark.streaming._
 import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ 
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
object SampleStream {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SampleStream")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
  val flumeStream = FlumeUtils.createPollingStream(ssc, "localhost", 1234)
  ssc.stop()
  }
}
```

**i am using SBT to build Jar my SBT configuration is below:**

```
name := "Flume"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
publishMavenStyle := true
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.4.1" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume_2.10" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.10.4"
resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

**The problem is now i can get build my jar without any error but while running i am getting the below error:**

```
16/04/11 19:52:56 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/FlumeUtils$
        at com.thagna.twtsteam.SampleStream$.main(SampleStream.scala:10)
        at com.thanga.twtsteam.SampleStream.main(SampleStream.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeUtils$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 11 more
16/04/11 19:52:56 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

**can anyone help to get resolve**

Comment: with which plugin you create the jar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use --jars option if you are running the job using spark-submit

For Ex:

```
spark-submit --jars ....../lib/spark-streaming_2.10-1.2.1‌​.2.2.6.0-2800.jar
```

or
add this to your SBT configuration

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-flume" % "2.1.0"
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your build to get rid of this error:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-flume_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-flume_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```